# планирование отправки письма в yii2

Tags: php, yii2

мне надо заплонировать отправку письма после того как пройдет 5дней с data1_start, на email адреса заполненных данных

или так

есть таблица data_start с датой старта и после того как пройдет 5 дней надо отправить письмо на e_mail адреса который был заполнен в таблице human

Comment: В чем собственно проблема?

Comment: написать условие  что email адреса лежат не в отдельной таблице, а в таблице human и в строке email, и  протестировать на локалке

Answer (score 0):

Пишите в любой контроллер (допустим SiteController) отдельный action (допустим actionEmail) который проверяет нужное условие и отправляет сообщение. Затем на сервере настраиваете cron который в нужное время выполняет скрипт по адресу `sitename.ru/site/email`. Всё просто.

**UPD:**

Пример условия:

```
public function actionEmail() {
  $humans = Human::find()->all();
  foreach($humans as $human) {
    $interval = intval(time() - strtotime($human->data1_start)) / (3600 * 24); //количество дней между датой из базы и текущей датой
    if($interval >= 5) {
      $human->sendEmail();
    }
  }
}
```

Что то в этом роде. Не знаю верно ли понял Ваш вопрос.

Comment: в том то и дело я всё это должен протестировать в локальном OpenServer, и мне надо написать условие

Comment: из тех входных данных которые Вы описали в вопросе Вам тут мало чем помогут. сейчас опишу примерное условие, исходя из того, как я понял задачу

Comment: изменил ответ..

Comment: есть таблица data_start с датой старта и после того как пройдет 5 дней надо отправить письмо на e_mail адрес который был заполнен в таблице human

Answer (score 0):

Настраиваешь крон, чтобы раз в сутки запускал необходимый файл. В этом файле делаешь выборку из таблицы всех строк, у которых time_send, к примеру, равен текущему дню. Выборку проходишь в цикле, проверяешь адрес, формируешь тело письма и отправляешь. После отправки пишешь айпишник записи в массив, чтобы потом удалить записи или отметить их.
Чтобы письма отправлялись через определенное время, в таблицу в поле time_send пиши время текущее, когда произошло событие, плюс пять дней.
time () + 86400 * 5

Comment: а крон можно ли настроить на локальном сервере, в моем случаи Open Server?

Comment: Да, в вашем случае можно крон настроить. Настройки - планировщик.