# как тормознуть или остановить

Tags: php, yii2

проблема такова что она отправляет письма каждый раз как страница обновляется
как это выполнить только один раз

```
<?= GridView::widget([
'rowOptions'=>function($model){
    $dun = "success";
    if
    ( date("Y-m-d", strtotime($model->data_okon. "-10 days")) <=  date("Y-m-d") ) {
        $dun = 'warning';
        mail('$to','Срок 2','Срок ваш 2 истекает через 10 дней');
    }
    if( date("Y-m-d", strtotime($model->data_okon. "-5 days")) <=  date("Y-m-d") ){
        $dun = 'danger';
    }
    return [
        'class' => $dun,
        mail('$to','Срок 3','Срок ваш 3 истекает через 5 дней')
    ];

},
```

Comment: Кто она? На примере только вывод таблицы, без отправки

Comment: @YaroslavMolchan а `mail()` в конце что по вашему делает?

Comment: вот как ее тормознуть)

Comment: не ожидал его там увидеть, ну по идее такие вещи должны делаться на кроне, по моему вам уже давали советы по этому поводу - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/721723/%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%B2-yii2 . В вашем же случае если клиент не зайдет он и не узнает что у него истекает срок.

Comment: да этот код выполняется каждый раз как страница обновляется, а мне хотелось бы только через 10 и через 5 дней

Comment: @YaroslavMolchan мне надо не планировать а отправлять по условию

Comment: ну так так крон работает, создаете скрипт который будет запускаться каждый день, в нём ваше условие и всё

Comment: а вот крон можно ли запустить на локальном сервере?

Answer (score 0):

Есть такое чудное приложение

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Напишите отдельный скрипт на отправку сообщений на почту, и запускайте проверку каждые сутки, например. Если дата подошла к нужному порогу, то отправляем сообщение, если нет, то дела нет и ждем следующих суток.